# how to get view rotation in android

Tags: android

how to get view rotation in android api level < 11?

i can set rotation of view using below code :

```
 private void rotate(float degree,View v) {
    final RotateAnimation rotateAnim = new RotateAnimation(0.0f, degree,
            RotateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f,
            RotateAnimation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);

    rotateAnim.setDuration(0);
    rotateAnim.setFillAfter(true);
    v.startAnimation(rotateAnim);

}
```

but how to get view rotation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if its just view rotate then u may use canvas.rotate() by overwriting onDraw method.